# set polyLine Path using Json Arrary

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-maps

i have created a Method which returns array of Latitude and longitude from database using c#, now i want to pass this list to JavaScript to bind poly_line path on google maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
}
poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);

var path = new MVCArray;

$.getJSON('json.cs', function(data) {
    //var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.longi));
    });

    // now update your polyline to use this path
    poly.setPath(path);
});


<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:90%; height:100%"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

[For Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/polyline.html)

Comment: can you specify how do i code in c# to get json array here???

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i